# Count distinct values of a field in a file

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a file with one million lines. Each line has a field called `transactionid`, which has repetitive values. What I need to do is to count them distinctly. No matter how many times a value is repeated, it should be counted only once.

Comment: it would be more easier, if you could just give a glimpse of format of the file..not necessarily the data.

Comment: btw, do you want the value to be counted as 1 irrespective of how many times it exists, or you want the count of the number of occurrences/repetitions? if you just want it to be counted once, then how the distinct values are counted? Can you please check my edit on your question and confirm if I am right in interpreting.

Comment: @Nikhil This is clear from the question: `... No matter of how many times a value is repeated, it should be counted as 1. ...`

Comment: ok, then answer from @hesse would do your need.

Comment: sorry for latency. I was out of internet connection. seperator is 2|' and field is field 28. I used;

`cat <file_name> | awk -F"|" '{if ((substr($2,0,8)=='20120110')) print $28}' | sort -u | wc -l`

the if clause was for another check of date as it seems obvious :)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

OK, Assuming that your file is a text file, having the fields separated by comma separator ','. You would also know which field `'transactionid'` is in terms of its position.  Assuming that your `'transactionid'` field is 7th field.

```
awk -F ',' '{print $7}' text_file | sort | uniq -c
```

This would count the distinct/unique occurrences in the 7th field and prints the result.

Comment: Why `sort` before `uniq` command.

Comment: @g10guang Becasue for `uniq` to eliminate records they need to be next to each other.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe not the sleekest method, but this should work:

```
awk '{print $1}' your_file | sort | uniq | wc -l
```

where `$1` is the number corresponding to the field to be parsed.

Comment: that gives you the number of distinct values plus 1 (header). How can we avoid the counter to include header?

Comment: @neverMind Just tell `awk` to exclude the headers from printing: `awk 'NR>1 {print $1}' | ...`

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to sort the file ..  (`uniq` requires the file to be sorted)
This awk script assumes the field is the first whitespace delimiited field.

```
awk 'a[$1] == "" { a[$1]="X" } END { print length(a) }' file
```

Comment: For a huge file (as in, getting close to the size of RAM), awk will consume a lot of memory. Most `sort` implementations are designed to cope well with huge files.